# Angular Filter with not like

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a angular select box

```
      <select class="form-control"  
                    data-ng-model="concept.type" 
                    data-ng-options="t for t in myTypes" 
                    required>
               <option value="">-- Choose a type --</option>
      </select>
```

and in my controller

```
 $scope.myTypes = ["Simple","Complex","EmptySimple","EmptyComplex"]
```

I want to show only `Simple and Complex` in the options, i.e. I want to filter out any values which starts with Empty. How can i do it apart from filtering it out in the controller?

Comment: You could write a custom filter for those options. and use it like data-ng-options="t for t in myTypes | removeEmpty"

Comment: Adding to the one above me, you could write a directive, but that will be too much for this kind of problem I think

Comment: hmmm, looks like in filtering it out first and setting up another variable looks much less complication.

Comment: @neolivz4ever you would use the same code either way if you made new variable or created custom angular filter. try making a custom filter so you then know how for more complicated issues in the future

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, makes sense. So in the same control file i define the filter or I create a separate file for the filter?

Comment: which file really isn't critical since we don't know your file structure.

Comment: I am just curious as I don't have a custom filter so far. So what is the best practice related with custom filter? I have conventional angular structure. Each module has a module.js & controler and templates and services.

Comment: not sure if you create `directives.js` , could have `filters.js`  totally up to you ... or in same file as controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter a into select tag

```
<select class="form-control"   
                    data-ng-model="concept.type" 
                    data-ng-options="t for t in myTypes | | filter:{ t : '"\"Empty"\"' }" 
                    required>
               <option value="">-- Choose a type --</option>
      </select>
```

From the docs: [Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)